# WPF Applying a trigger on binding failure

Tags: wpf, data-binding, triggers

This question is a follow on from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589194/wpf-binding-failure-performance-hit-vs-exception)...

I am binding to a heterogeneous collection of objects, not all objects have the same set of properties. I am doing this in a datagrid. I would like to gray out the cell if the binding fails. Is there a way to apply a trigger if a binding fails?

EDIT: The answer below was suitable for my purposes, but i followed up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597378/wpf-trigger-on-dependencyproperty-unsetvalue) because I would like to know how to do it (in a non hack fashion - i do love the hack however, don't get me wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this directly.  However, if you can identify a value that will never be returned from successful bindings, you can create a DataTrigger whose binding has that value as its FallbackValue, and trigger on that same value:

```
<!-- Hibble returns only positive values -->
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Hibble, FallbackValue=-1}" Value="-1">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

In theory it might be possible to omit the FallbackValue and trigger on `{x:Static DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}`, which would be much cleaner, but this doesn't appear to work in practice.

Comment: lovely bit of magic number programming there, gotta love it. think ill ask the question on triggering on unset value however, see what the community comes up with