# Binding errors in WPF application

Tags: wpf, performance

I have developed a WPF application without resolving the Binding Errors. Now in debug mode we found many binding errors. It is sure that in Debug mode the Binding errors will degrade application performance.
Could someone please tell me whether in Release mode the binding errors will affect the performance? Sharing any valid links supporting these facts will be appreciable.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't fix the binding errors before you deploy it?

Comment: I am ready to fix the binding errors. But it take huge effort to find those errors, because of its size. I want to know whether any performance degradation will occur in release mode.

Comment: http://pelebyte.net/blog/2011/07/11/twelve-ways-to-improve-wpf-performance/#FixBindingErrors

Comment: Read this SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589194/wpf-binding-failure-performance-hit-vs-exception).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will get performance hits with broken bindings. However, they will be larger hits in debug mode because of the console output.

I suggested fixing the bindings. If you expect null sources use the `FallbackValue` property of `Binding`.